# Missing MailHeader fields when accessing IUploadMailData in custom UploadOperationHandler (harmon.ie outlook plugin)

Tags: outlook-addin, sharepoint-online, harmon.ie

I am trying to access the "To"-Field in the mail header while hooking into the UploadOperation of an email item in the Harmon.ie Outlook addin (to rename the file using some defaults when uploading to sharepoint).

For some reason the only header fields I get from the uploaded item are `Received`, `Date` and  `From`.

What I currently do is iterating the `IUploadItemData` elements in the `IWrappedList` inside the `onBeforeUpload` handler.
Then checking for items of type `IUploadMailItemData` and trying to access their `MetaDataValue` fields using the `Harmonie.SDK.MailHeader` class constants as keys. But as already mentioned I only get the 3 fields `Received`, `Date` and  `From`.

What am I doing wrong? May I load the other header fields somehow too?

Answer (score 0):

Are you customer?
I am asking because our SDK is only accessible from the Enterprise edition (not the free edition, our forum is for users running the free edition).
If you are customer, please disclose the name of your company and send a support request to support@harmon.ie

----- Jean